# Is it worth using a multithreaded blas implementation along with multiprocessing in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy, multiprocessing, blas

Suppose I have a 16 core machine, and an embarrassingly parallel program.  I use lots of numpy dot products and addition of numpy arrays, and if I did not use multiprocessing it would be a no-brainer:  Make sure numpy is built against a version of blas that uses multithreading.  However, I am using multiprocessing, and all cores are working hard at all times.  In this case, is there any benefit to be had from using a multithreading blas?

Most of the operations are (blas) type 1, some are type 2.

Answer (score 6):

You might need to be a little careful about the assumption that your code is actually used multithreaded BLAS calls. Relatively few numpy operators actually use the underlying BLAS, and relatively few BLAS calls are actually multithreaded. `numpy.dot` uses either BLAS `dot`, `gemv` or `gemm`, depending on the operation, but of those, only `gemm` is usually multithreaded, because there is rarely any performance benefit for the O(N) and O(N^2) BLAS calls in doing so. If you are limiting yourself to Level 1 and Level 2 BLAS operations, I doubt you are actually using *any* multithreaded BLAS calls, even if you are using a numpy implementation built with a mulithreaded BLAS, like Atlas or MKL.

Comment: I am interested in sources explaining this behavior if you know some internet document about it...

Comment: The obvious source is the numpy code itself. Beyond that, both Clint Whaley (author of Atlas, formerly from UTK) and Kazushige Goto (author of GotoBLAS, formerly from TACC) have written and published a number of design documents and academic papers on their BLAS implementations and their performance.

Answer (score 2):

If you are already using multiprocessing, and all cores are at max load, then there will be very little, if any, benefit to adding threads that will be waiting around for a processor.

Depending on your algorithm and what you're doing, it may be more beneficial to use one type over the other, but that's very dependent.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding things, but I was under the impression that one processor core can efficiently use multiple threads.  So you can get a speedup on a one-core machine.

Comment: I'm not an expert in multiprocessing/threading (yet!) but to my understanding, if a single processor is at max load, adding more threads will only cause more overhead to swapping between them. Unless there is special architecture to help handle other threads while one is working (say, another core?) no performance increase will occur. If all of the cores are at max load and if you split the same job into small chunks, they will all still be at max load. Adding threads to a single core machine is useful when the core is waiting around for something to happen.